# GTK2.0 is installed but unable to locate when compiling

Tags: c, gtk

I am brand new to GTK and looking to compile my first program with it. Upon compiling I get the following error:

```
randall@randall-ubuntu:~/c_programs/bettingCalc$ gcc -o bettingCalc main.c
main.c:8:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

The typical solution seems to be running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Which I ran, and seemingly successfully installed. What am I missing here?

if it is at all relevant, here is the last 8 lines of the installation process:

```
Setting up libxcomposite-dev (1:0.4.4-1) ...
Setting up x11proto-damage-dev (1:1.2.1-2) ...
Setting up libxdamage-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxml2-utils (2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4) ...
Setting up libgtk2.0-dev (2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libsys-hostname-long-perl (1.4-3) ...
Setting up libmail-sendmail-perl (0.79.16-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
randall@randall-ubuntu:~/c_programs/bettingCalc$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use gtk-config in compile/link cycle to get info about installed GTK

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/gtk-config.1.html

UPDATE: gtk-config is depreciated, please use pkg-config to achieve desired result and get right
includes, flags and library references

For compilation

```
gcc -c main.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

For linking

```
gcc -o app main.o `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Comment: umm... what about ```pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0``` ?

Comment: that yielded
`-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype  
randall@randall-ubuntu:~$ `

Comment: cool, that will work. Use it in you command like `gcc -c aaa.c -o aaa.o \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+2.0\` `

Comment: Finally got \` quoted right! So use it like I proposed in the comment above, and all includes, options etc shall be injected right into compilation command. Same for linking but use --libs instead of --cflags

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! However I'm still not quite there yet. Here is my output when using your tip `randall@randall-ubuntu:~/c_programs/bettingCalc$ gcc -o bettingCalc main.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+2.0`
Package gtk+2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+2.0' found
main.c:13:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.` sorry for the format, the ` is throwing me off

Comment: I tried `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/Downloads/gtk+-2.24.23/` as the error message implied, but I got the same error afterwards.

Comment: ummm... But you've got output from `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`, right? Just 3 comments above? So it is in your path. To inject it into compilation line you have to quote pkg-config command with \`

Comment: Just for compilation, try to execute following command: `gcc -c main.c \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+2.0\` `

Comment: Note that pkg-config call (with all options) is quoted with \`, thus its output will be inserted into your command-line

Comment: you need to use 'back ticks' which, on my keyboard, are just left of the '1' key on the top left corner of the keyboard. YMMV Your keyboard my have the char in a different location, however, it definately is not on the same key as a " (double quote)

Comment: I'm certain that I'm using the correct `, and here is my output from that last command... still unable to find gtk 'randall@randall-ubuntu:~/c_programs/bettingCalc$ gcc -c main.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+2.0`
Package gtk+2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+2.0' found
main.c:13:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.'

Comment: Randy, I think I know what the problem is: you requested gtk+2.0, but you need gtk+-2.0, there is a dash between package name (gtk+) and package version. `gcc -c main.c \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0\` `

Comment: That did it! thank you so much Severin! Do I need to run this command every time I compile? Or is there a practical way to set it up to where I can compile with simply gcc main.c

Comment: Great! Well, if you use Makefile, I would guess you could assign output of pkg-config to some variable and refer to it later, but it won't save you much, this approach basically asking you to do it each and every time. And remember `pkg-config --cflags ...` gives you includes and flags for compilation, and `pkg-config --libs ...` gives you libraries for linking. Good luck

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Would be great if you could update the answer to mention pkg-config and not gtk-config. The latter has been deprecated for about 15 years.